# How to set property file path in classpath from tmp directory of weblogic server?

Tags: java, weblogic

I have created one stand alone java application, in which one config.property is used and which placed under `/tmp/MyReport/config` folder of weblogic server. I tried adding it like below but java didn't found it.

```
**set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;/tmp/MyReport/config/;/tmp/MyReport/logs/;**
```

And then

```
java -jar /tmp/MyReport/lib/Reports.jar com.bt.quartz.ReportsMain
```

Above two line of code was executed through `.sh` file but no luck. Please suggest solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted property file in the same directory where jar resides and then it worked.